# Top down water view, cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, particles, water

Has anyone successfully created a top down view of a stream/river? I need to also work out how to make it look like a boat is cutting through the water.

Comment: Yes people have successfully done that before. Your question is very open ended. Try to ask questions for specific problems you're having. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) about what types of questions to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for to simulate the surface of water.

http://thebackfiregames.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/ripples/

Comment: Thank you, I've also downloaded particle designer, there are a few particle systems on their which look useful, but this is brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to animate particles in a wave fashion, so that each particle's velocity is affected by - 1. wave motion over time 2. the opposite of the boat's velocity ... and move each particle over time.