# What fluid simulation system is used in iPhone games?

Tags: iphone, physics, water

Does anybody know what kind of system developers are using for fluid simulation in iPhone games? It doesn't seem like they're using a Navier-Strokes simulation to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the blog:
http://mediocregames.wordpress.com/

Posts like this might help you:
http://mediocregames.wordpress.com/2011/09/08/getting-the-water-flowing/

They are the makers of Sprinkle:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sprinkle-water-splashing-fire/id447791438?mt=8
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mediocre.sprinkle&hl=en

Answer (score 2):

My game is 2D so I'm using a particle emitter to get a water effect.

If you're looking at using a 3d engine see:

http://benbritten.com/2009/05/19/fun-with-unity/

The particle emitter I'm using can be found on 71squared.

Also see:

[Top down water view, cocos2d](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30894/top-down-water-view-cocos2d)